# com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.UserCancellationException: Unknown error in Android using Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Hey Everyone I am facing the same error:

```
2020-07-24 21:26:34.918 16841-16841/com.nts.newssafe E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.UserCancellationException: Unknown error
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.GoogleSignInHandler.onActivityResult(GoogleSignInHandler.java:104)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.idp.SingleSignInActivity.onActivityResult(SingleSignInActivity.java:142)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4477)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4524)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1691)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

When logging in using email with domain @gmail.com the sign is getting successful but when signing in using custom domain address of Google apps account like company domain email it is failing with this specific error. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if you know this answer plz tell me i also face same issue .thanks